# Orientation of boundary domain normals

Tags: bugs, mesh, finite-element-method

**Bug introduced in 11.2.0 or earlier, and fixed in 11.3.0**

---

I would like to use BoundaryNormals provided by the ElementMesh object. To demonstrate my problem I will take my favorite domain:

```
dom = ImplicitRegion[(x - 1/2)^2 + (y - 1/2)^2 >= (1/4)^2, {{x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}}];
bmesh = ToBoundaryMesh[dom];
mesh = ToElementMesh[dom];
normals = bmesh["BoundaryNormals"];
```

I copied the example to show the orientation of normals:

```
mean = Mean /@ GetElementCoordinates[bmesh["Coordinates"], #] & /@ 
   ElementIncidents[bmesh["BoundaryElements"]];
Show[ListPlot[First@mesh, AspectRatio -> 1, PlotRange -> {{-0.1, 1.1}, {-0.1, 1.1}}], 
Graphics[MapThread[
   Arrow[{#1, #2}] &, {Join @@ mean, Join @@ (normals/15 + mean)}]]]
```

Now it's obvious, that something's off: outer boundary normals are oriented away from the domain, whereas inner (circle) normals are oriented toward the domain:

[image]

I would like to have all normals oriented either towards the domain or away from domain, but not like this, inconsistently. This could be done manually by checking the dot product with the closest non-boundary point, however, I suspect it has something to do how Mathematica circles around the domain: if it's clockwise, then the said normal is oriented away, if counter-clockwise, it's oriented the other way around.

Comment: Congrats on finding a solution to your problem! For the benefit of this site, definitely encourage posting your solution as an answer to your question.  This way when people [search](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=boundary+domain+normals) they'll see this question as having an answer (accepted or not).  Right now it looks like XX votes up, 0 answers in search results.

Comment: Okay, thanks, will do.

Comment: I filed this as a bug - all normals should point outward (opposite to what you unified them to in yout answer)

Comment: This will be fixed in the next release (post V11.2) and the normal will point outward.

Comment: @user21 Thank you, I appreciate that. However, since I tried to come up with some mesh-generating algorithm myself, I was quite stunned how come Mathematica have not messed it up without properly knowing orientation of normals. I always use this information to tell whether I am "inside" or "outside" the domain, not to mention that all kinds of advancing fronts rely heavily on knowing to which side should they propagate - again, the concept of a properly oriented normal is crucial.

Comment: Meshing is typically done be meshing the entire region (including internal holes) and then there is a seed point (in a region hole) which tells the mesh generator with elements need to be removed. FEM also never needs the boundary normal. So boundary normals are just provided as a conveniance; the only FEM function that uses it is the grouping of boundaries and there the direction of the normal does not matter. So for ElementMesh normals are not crucial at all.

Comment: That's really weird considering there are also Neumann BCs (besides Dirichlet which really doesn't need normal vectors). How it's the solution to the Neumann problem implemented internally if it doesn't utilize the normal vector(s)? :O

Comment: Hi user16320, I've been looking at all your very interesting questions on boundary normals. Here's a different approach I thought up this morning; recall that the gradient of a potential is normal to equipotential surfaces. So if we solve a heat/voltage equation with internal source/charge and fixed value on the boundary, `u = NDSolveValue[{Laplacian[f[x, y], {x, y}] == 1, DirichletCondition[f[x, y] == 0, True]}, f, Element[{x, y}, mesh]]` the field `n = Grad[u[x, y], {x, y}] // Normalize` will be the outward unit normal when evaluated on the boundary. (`VectorPlot[n, Element[{x, y}, mesh]]`)

Comment: Also if you want, I can post the above method as an answer, but I'm not quite sure if it is completely relevant (since the question is about `"BoundaryNormals"`).

Comment: @user16320, I only saw your last question now (use @user21 to ping me), `NeumannValue` never computes a normal to do it's job because the boundary integral is replaced by the neumann value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I somehow found a solution. It's very straightforward and not a bit too elegant.

First we define several things to get started with (look [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/ref/ElementMesh.html) and [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/154698/boundarymesh-correctly-pair-boundary-points-with-normals) to understand details, in short: the interior and boundary coordinates need to be separate and normals must correspond to exact points on the boundary to proceed with the flipping):

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
d = 0.0005;
dom = ImplicitRegion[(x - 1/2)^2 + (y - 1/2)^2 >= (1/4)^2, {{x, 0, 
     1}, {y, 0, 1}}];
grid = ToElementMesh[dom, "MeshOrder" -> 1, MaxCellMeasure -> d][
   "Coordinates"];
bmesh = ToBoundaryMesh[dom, "MeshOrder" -> 1, MaxCellMeasure -> d];
boundary = Partition[Flatten@bmesh["Coordinates"], 2];
normals = Partition[Flatten@bmesh["BoundaryNormals"], 2];
interior = Complement[grid, boundary, SameTest -> (Norm[#1 - #2] < d &)];
e = bmesh["BoundaryElements"];
elements = 
  Join @@ (GetElementCoordinates[boundary, #] & /@ 
     ElementIncidents[e]);
n = Table[
   Normalize[
    Mean /@ Transpose@
      normals[[First@
         Transpose@Position[elements, boundary[[i]]]]]], {i, 1, 
    Length@boundary}];
```

Now the normals are correctly paired with the boundary coordinates, but they can point either toward or away from the domain. To fix that, just check the dot product with the closest interior point and if it's negative, flip the normal:

```
For[i = 1, i <= Length@n, i++,
 v = First@Drop[Nearest[interior, boundary[[i]], 2], 1] - 
   boundary[[i]];
 If[v.n[[i]] < 0, n[[i]] = -n[[i]]];
 ]
```

This produces the result I've been looking for:

[image]

Feel free to clean up the code.

**EDIT**: user John Joseph M. Carrasco provided me with those so much needed improvements that are explained in [this short article](https://gist.github.com/drjjmc/ad787f4f186aacd745444eca402d6ad1). I am very thankful to him for explaining how the syntax works. In the end, this:

```
n = Table[
   Normalize[
    Mean /@ Transpose@
      normals[[First@
         Transpose@Position[elements, boundary[[i]]]]]], {i, 1, 
    Length@boundary}];
```

can be replaced with:

```
Normalize@Mean@normals[[First /@ Position[elements, #]]] & /@ boundary;
```

and the flipping:

```
For[i = 1, i <= Length@n, i++,
 v = First@Drop[Nearest[interior, boundary[[i]], 2], 1] - 
   boundary[[i]];
 If[v.n[[i]] < 0, n[[i]] = -n[[i]]];
 ]
```

with a much shorter version:

```
n[[Select[Range@Length@n, n[[#]].((Nearest[interior, #, 2][[2]] - #) &@boundary[[#]]) < 0 &]]] *= -1;
```

Comment: just for fun: Instead of your table def'n of $n$, can use: `n = Normalize@Mean@normals[[First /@ Position[elements, #]]] & /@ 
   boundary;`   also, instead of  using `For` loop to flip signs:  `n[[Select[Range@Length@n, 
     n[[#]].((Nearest[interior, #, 2][[2]] - #) &@boundary[[#]]) < 
       0 &]]] *= -1;`

Comment: No, no it's not just for fun! This is EXACTLY the kind of corrections I need! What I wrote is not a proper Mathematica code, it's clumsy and c++-like. I will adjust the code so it's more elegant due to your suggestion. Thank you very much ^_^

Although...as I look at your code, as much as it works, I do not understand it :( I can understand what @, @@ and @@@ is, what /@ does, but there are too many strange characters...

Comment: I'll make some notes to walk from your expressions to the ones above and place a link here (relatively soon).

Comment: Didn't seem appropriate to use an answer to clarify my comment so made a markdown file with notes on gist [here](https://gist.github.com/drjjmc/ad787f4f186aacd745444eca402d6ad1).  Please feel free to ask any questions.

Comment: Thank you! Honestly, you're the best dude ever to make this effort to explain to me how can one arrive at that code compression...I just lol'd so hard at "badGuys" and how you omit them in the end. Can I append that link to the answer so people find it and learn something from it? It's a display of elegant coding!

Comment: Sure feel free.  It was of course no problem, pedagogic impulse is why stackexchange works, right?

Comment: Can I ask you a question? How do you usually code things like these? At first you make it "c++ way" and then gradually shape it into Mathematica compressed form with @#&/, or you directly code in that way?

Comment: And can you help me with one more? I have this (offset = 0.01): For[i=1,i<=Length@boundary,i++,
 grid = Append[grid, boundary[[i]] + offset n[[i]]];
  interior = Append[interior, boundary[[i]] + offset n[[i]]];
 ]

According to your tutorial I changed it to: Map[
 AppendTo[grid, #1 + offset #2];
   AppendTo[interior, #1 + offset #2];
   &[boundary, n]
 ]

However, it does not work :( what am I doing wrong? I'm using those pure variables, &, [bla, blabla] replaces both #1 and #2...so why isn't it working?

Comment: "At first you make it "c++ way" and then gradually shape it into Mathematica compressed form with @#&/, or you directly code in that way?" - it takes (lots of) practice (and unlearning habits obtained from using other languages), but you do eventually get used to programming functionally instead of programming procedurally.

Comment: 1)  Re: "c++ vs mma" after refactoring code for efficiency you just start to internalize heuristic aesthetics around what mma likes and what grinds its gears.  It's ok to sketch in your comfort language -- it will evolve.  2) I think refactoring questions and why-didn't-this-work (especially when you start with something that does work like your `For` loop) are great actual questions (not just comment Q's) for this site + you'll get a wide spectrum of answers. In this case you want something like: `{grid, interior} = Join[#, boundary + offset n] & /@ {grid, interior};`

Comment: This is great! Thank you, although I don't know why my version doesn't work :( I tried to follow your advices on the link you posted here... :D Mathematica is a mysterious creature!

Comment: 'Map' needs 2 arguments or it becomes an operator.  Note your commas: only one argument and it didn't operate on anything.  (So it had nothing to loop over) You made an anonymous function inside the map. If it ever ran it would ignore anything map handed it and append an entire list as elements to your other lists.

Comment: So then perhaps Apply = over list of pairs would resemble what I tried to do? I think that something similar worked, like Set @@@ ({{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}}) makes x1=y1, x2=y2, ...but your version is easier :D

Answer (score 4):

This is fixed in Version 11.3:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
dom = ImplicitRegion[(x - 1/2)^2 + (y - 1/2)^2 >= (1/4)^2, {{x, 0, 
     1}, {y, 0, 1}}];
bmesh = ToBoundaryMesh[dom];
mesh = ToElementMesh[dom];
normals = bmesh["BoundaryNormals"];
mean = Mean /@ GetElementCoordinates[bmesh["Coordinates"], #] & /@ 
   ElementIncidents[bmesh["BoundaryElements"]];
Show[ListPlot[First@mesh, AspectRatio -> 1, 
  PlotRange -> {{-0.1, 1.1}, {-0.1, 1.1}}], 
 Graphics[MapThread[
   Arrow[{#1, #2}] &, {Join @@ mean, Join @@ (normals/15 + mean)}]]]
```

[image]

Comment: Keep up the good job!

Comment: @user16320, thanks for the encouragement!